# When formatting TypeScript in visual studio code, a cast generates tslint whitespace warning

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, code-formatting, tslint, editorconfig

For example, when I have the following TypeScript code

`const bar = <foo>{ answer: 42 }`

tslint issues a warning 'missing whitespace' between `>` and `{`. So, to fix it, I have to write:

`const bar = <foo> { answer: 42 }`

However, every time I format my file in vs code (SHIFT+ALT+F), my formatting is reset to the version at the top, causing a new tslint issue. As I cannot change the formatting rules in vs code, do I need to add a rule to tslint or editorconfig?

Comment: what does `tslint.json` contain?

Comment: {
  "extends": "tslint:recommended",
  "rules": {
    "quotemark": [true, "single", "double"],
    "max-line-length": [200],
    "whitespace": [true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ],
    "trailing-comma": [true, {
      "multiline": "never",
      "singleline": "never"
    }],
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the tslint.json and edit [`whitespace`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/whitespace/) rule in your project.
Your example looks like the `check-typecast` setting.

> "check-typecast" checks for whitespace between a typecast and its target.

As suggested override your rule set with:

```
"whitespace": [true, "check-branch", "check-decl", "check-operator", "check-separator", "check-type" ]
```

Comment: thanks, that works! 
The whitespace rule is part of the tslint:recommended rule set, so I had to explicitly override it using the rule:
```
"whitespace": [true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ],
```

Comment: glad it worked out :).. I will update my answer with your comment.

Answer (score -1):

```
  "typedef-whitespace": [
  true,
  {
    "call-signature": "nospace",
    "index-signature": "nospace",
    "parameter": "nospace",
    "property-declaration": "nospace",
    "variable-declaration": "nospace"
  },
  {
    "call-signature": "onespace",
    "index-signature": "onespace",
    "parameter": "onespace",
    "property-declaration": "onespace",
    "variable-declaration": "onespace"
  }
```

Comment: because format of declaration is custom my angular this is disadvantage but you can specify the that code in tslint.json to resolve your white-space error

Comment: you can also use in space,nospace ,onespace in same place

Comment: Your answer came up in the review queue. On SO we prefer that answers include the explanation.  Though the code may fix the problem the explanation helps others to learn from their mistakes.